# Where may one get sample 3d environments?

Tags: testing, 3d, rendering, collada

I want to test my 3d rendering engine as it gets developed, but I am using really lame objects like COLLADA models and such.

I was wondering if anyone knew about a repository where one could download full 3d scenes, like cities, but not full levels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classic test model is the Sponza Atrium scene (http://hdri.cgtechniques.com/~sponza/files/) by Marko Dabrovic.

[image: sponza]
<sub>(source: [webfactional.com](http://roi.webfactional.com/img/so/sponza.jpg))</sub>

There are many, many images of this scene from different rendering engines around, so you have lots to compare your results to.

Otherwise, here are some other useful model sites:

- http://www.turbosquid.com
- http://www.modelup.com
- http://www.archibase.net/gdl
- http://modelsbank.3dm3.com
- http://www.max-realms.com
- http://www.3dlands.com
- http://www.evermotion.org/
- http://archive3d.net/

Comment: A recent high-res update of the Sponza Atrium scene (among other widely used test models) can be found here:  http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/data/meshes.xml